# submit button being created inside of submit button

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm having a problem with a submit button in a form, when clicked it first reloads the current page, which creates a submit button inside of the original one before posting to the post page.

You can see the behavior example here:

http://tampary.com/pick_game.php?c_id=15&p_id=0&f_id=1&l_id=1

You can click back in your browser after clicking "start game" and you will see the nested controls. Using Chrome and Firefox, you get same results. Any ideas what could be causing this behavior? ideally, I just want the php page to be redirected to after the form submit to just load up cleanly. Any help would be greatly appreciated

The complete code is as follows:

```
<?php
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/grl-lib/db.php');
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/grl-lib/ui.php');
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/grl-lib/family.php');  
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/grl-lib/location.php');        
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/grl-lib/contact.php');     
    $ui = new x_ui;
    $ui->set_ui(1);
    if (!empty($_POST)){
        $p_id = $_POST['p_id'];
        $f_id = $_POST['f_id'];
        $l_id = $_POST['l_id']; 
        $c_id = $_POST['c_id'];
    }else{
        $p_id = $_GET['p_id'];
        $f_id = $_GET['f_id'];
        $l_id = $_GET['l_id'];      
        $c_id = $_GET['c_id'];
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="<?php echo $ui->getLocale($ui->language_id,1); ?>">
<head>
    <?php include_once('grl-lib/gen_include.php'); ?>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex"> <!-- no indexing this page -->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/devices.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Tampary<?php ' '._('game'); ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">    
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body class="color_bg">

    <?php include('standard/header.txt'); ?>
    <!-- all content -->    
    <div class="entire_content_length aling_text_c">
        <div class="max_width_responsive align_container_c spc_a_5">
            <div class="align_container_c spc_a_5 container_c">
                    <form id="pick_game" action="game.php" method="post">
                    <?php
                        $html = '<input type="hidden" name="p_id" id="p_id" value="'.$p_id.'"><input type="hidden" name="f_id" id="f_id" value="'.$f_id.'"><input type="hidden" name="l_id" id="l_id" value="'.$l_id.'"><input type="hidden" name="c_id" id="c_id" value="'.$c_id.'">';
                        //$html = $html.'<input type="submit" value="'._('Start Game').'">';
                        echo $html;
                    ?>  
                    <input type="submit" value="Start Game">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php include('standard/footer.txt'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using an Ajax script, which is fine. But is definitely the culprit cause I can see it responding the entire page in firebug.

I will bet you that your front page is Ajax to and you append something somewhere (can't find it this fast).

Whatever the case, I'm not convinced that what ever your doing (loading an entire page through AJAX) is good practice.

Looking at your AJAX requests will solve your inception button problem

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for looking at it. I don't know exactly what you mean. What script do you think could be causing the issue?

Comment: You should be the one to figure that out. It is atleast some js script in there. Sparing your website with an enter for each line would definitly improve the read. Look for an append or prepend function. Its there somewhere, i promise you that.